# The relation between NP and IP(2pfa)

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, cr.crypto-security, np, interactive-proofs

As far as I know, it is not known whether $ \mathsf{NP} \subseteq \mathsf{IP(2pfa)} $, where $ \mathsf{IP(2pfa)} $ is the class of languages having interactive proof systems with some two-way probabilistic finite automata verifiers ([Finite state verifiers I: the power of interaction](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=146585.146599) by Dwork and Stockmeyer).

Does anybody know any progress on this issue?

I know the following results:

- $ \mathsf{IP(2pfa)} $ contains some NP-complete languages, where the verifier runs in poly-time.
- $ \mathsf{P} \subseteq \mathsf{IP(2pfa)} $, where the verifier runs in exp-time.
- $ \mathsf{DTIME(2^{O(n)})} \subseteq \mathsf{IP(2pfa)} $, where the verifier runs in double-exp-time.

Comment: Is $IP(2pfa)\subseteq NP$?

Comment: The best known upper for $ \mathsf{IP(2pfa)} $ is $ \mathsf{ATIME(2^{2^{O(n)}})} $ [Anne Condon, Richard J. Lipton: On the Complexity of Space Bounded Interactive Proofs (Extended Abstract) FOCS 1989: 462-467 (http://doi.ieeecomputersociety.org/10.1109/SFCS.1989.63519)].